# jquery-ui resize child divs also

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am creating a website I have divs which are resizable using jquery. When I resize them only the width of the child divs get resized. You can see the site and its code [here](http://98.url.ph/). How can the height of the child divs get resized too?

### Edit

Ok I solved it by adding this code:

```
  $(".window").resize(function() 
  {
     $(this).children('.inner').css(
     {
        height: $(this).height()-2
     });

     $(this).children().children('.content').css(
     {
        height: $(this).height()-$(this).children().children('.top').height()*2
     });
  });
```

Comment: see in this also you are getting the height of the div with class **inner**, but here you are getting by jquery.. you can simple do it by setting the css property of this inner class div **height=100%** i dont know why its not working for you **as you have said** but the both have the same meaning. !

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the child div height to 100%

in your case the div with class = "inner" need to have css property

```
div.inner
{
   height = 100%
}
```

[image]

Comment: http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/2746/3wve.png here you see it doesn't work even with height: 100%;

Comment: see actually u have 
**div_resizable -> dic.inner -> div.content**

and on dragging yu r changng the height width of div1 and u set the height = 100% of third div..  I am saying to set the height=100% of second div..

Comment: I am saying to set the height=100% of direct child of the parent div which you are resizing..

Comment: I understood and you can see that on my photo. But it does not work for me.

Comment: sorry to say but in your image its not clear what you have set.. I mean in your image you have not set the any height attribute check it again.. you have set the width and that is for **content** class div, I am talking about the div with class **inner** and set the height = 100% check my image

Comment: dude .. I have given you the proof.. Nw i dont know what you are saying and doing.. either lying or doing some mistake... As in image you set the **width=100% for div.Content**, in same way set the **height = 100% for its parent mean div with class=inner** and then try to resize the main div..

Comment: oh thats great.. then why dont you post you answer to that other poeple can see you answer too..